# How to Sort list of list as per user input?

Tags: python, list

I want to sort list of list according to the user input.

```
output = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]] # input
#           ^     ^     ^     ^
#           A     B     C     D
A = output[0] ; B = output[1] ; C = output[2] ; D = output[3] # initialization
userin = input('Enter sequence')
seq_list = userin.split(',')
print(seq_list)

>>> Enter sequence B,C,D,A
>>> ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A']
```

Python interprets input values as string, whereas i want those corresponding list to be reflected.

Expected output :

```
>>> Enter sequence B,C,D,A
>>> [[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: You can convert your list to dictionary and then print keys according to user's input.

Comment: Why not using numbers instead of letters and use them directly for indexing?

Comment: @grael ok let me try this with dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I've re-written the `output` variable as a dictionary using the stated letters as keys. Then it uses a list comprehension on `seq_list` to access the dictionary in the order the user has supplied.

```
output = {"A": [1,2], "B": [3,4],"C": [5,6],"D": [7,8]}
userin = input('Enter sequence')
seq_list = userin.split(',')
temp_list = [output[key] for key in seq_list]
print(temp_list)
```

Comment: Please provide some text explaining why this is a suitable solution and what it does

Comment: @hardillb if you can provide me better solution with explanation, its more than good,

Comment: @Tarun K The request for some explanation was not necessarily for your benefit, but for the next person who stumbles on to this via search. It was marked as a low quality answer, it's now better

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and the `zip` function to convert your `output` list of lists into a dict of lists.

```
output = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
d = {c: u for c, u in zip('ABCD', output)}
print(d)

userin = 'B,C,D,A'
seq_list = [d[c] for c in userin.split(',')]
print(seq_list)
```

**typical output**

```
{'C': [5, 6], 'B': [3, 4], 'A': [1, 2], 'D': [7, 8]}
[[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [1, 2]]
```

Python dictionaries are unordered, and in Python 3 the order that items of the dict `d` are printed in will change each time you run my code. Of course, that won't affect the order of sub-lists in `seq_list`

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to make user input numbers instead of letters. However, if you want to stick to letters you can just map them in a dictionary. My example approach looks like this:

```
output = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
output_dict = {i:elem for i, elem in enumerate(output)}
user_input = input('Enter sequence - numbers from 1 to 4 separated by comma')
print [output_dict[elem - 1] for elem in user_input]
```